# Perlbrew installation failed in the freebsd jail

Tags: perl

Just tried install `perlbrew` inside of the freebsd jail, with

```
perlbrew available
perlbrew install perl-5.20.2
```

finished with error

```
#   Failed test '[inet] syslog() should return true: '0''
#   at t/syslog.t line 180.

#   Failed test '[inet] syslog() should return true: '0''
#   at t/syslog.t line 187.

#   Failed test '[udp] syslog() should return true: '0''
#   at t/syslog.t line 180.

#   Failed test '[udp] syslog() should return true: '0''
#   at t/syslog.t line 187.
# Looks like you failed 4 tests of 225.
../cpan/Sys-Syslog/t/syslog.t ..................................... 
Dubious, test returned 4 (wstat 1024, 0x400)
Failed 4/225 subtests 
        (less 98 skipped subtests: 123 okay)
```

I know I could do:

```
perlbrew --notest install perl-5.20.2
perlbrew --force install perl-5.20.2
```

but don't know how "serious" are the above fails.

```
uname -a
FreeBSD example.com 9.0-RELEASE-p3 FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE-p3 #0: Tue Jun 12 02:52:29 UTC 2012     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was outside of perl. If such thing happens, check first your `syslogd` flags the `/etc/rc.conf`.

The `-ss` doesn't allows any connections via sockets, so the test fails. You can safely ignore this - or you can change the flags to:

```
-s -b localhost
```

and after this perlbrew will install perl without any errors.